ggplotly function changes position of labels in plot
I am creating a plot using ggplot package in R, however I need a plotly object at the end, therefore I am applying the ggplotly function. Unfortunately, this step changes the y-position of my bar labels. What can I change to prevent this from happening (or fix using plotly later)?
# initiate dataframe
my_data <- data.frame(type = c("friendly", "friendly", "friendly","friendly"),
                      gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female"),
                      level = c(1,1,2,2),
                      percent_change =c(10, 11, 9, 8))


# save the x variable
x_var <- unique(my_data$type)

# create the plot - with bar labels
gg <- ggplot(my_data) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = x_var, y = percent_change, fill = factor(level)), 
           stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(width = 1)) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x_var, y = percent_change, label = percent_change, group = interaction(x_var, level)), 
            position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#154273", "#e17000", "#39870c")) +  
  facet_wrap(~gender)

# transform to plotly object (messes up the labels!)
final_plot <- ggplotly(gg)


I already tried using correcting using plotly afterwards with textposition which didn't work out.

From my understanding of how plotly or ggplotly() work, the vjust parameter has no effect or is not passed on to the plotly object, most likely as there is no such argument or attribute in plotly. Instead, when using plotly the position of text is set via the textposition attribute, i.e. you can fix your issue and place the labels on top of the bars by setting the textposition= to "top" for the traces which add the labels. In your case these are the traces 5 and 6:
# initiate dataframe
my_data <- data.frame(
  type = c("friendly", "friendly", "friendly", "friendly"),
  gender = c("male", "female", "male", "female"),
  level = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  percent_change = c(10, 11, 9, 8)
)

# save the x variable
x_var <- unique(my_data$type)

library(plotly, warn = FALSE)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

gg <- ggplot(my_data) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = x_var, y = percent_change, fill = factor(level)),
    stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(width = 1)
  ) +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      x = x_var, y = percent_change, label = percent_change,
      group = interaction(x_var, level)
    ),
    position = position_dodge(width = 1), vjust = -0.5
  ) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#154273", "#e17000", "#39870c")) +
  facet_wrap(~gender)

ggp <- ggplotly(gg)

for (i in 5:6) {
  ggp$x$data[[i]]$textposition <- "top"
}
ggp


